# Why the sequence of html table is not changed if i change in jquery binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have an html table getting populated from JSON object returned from action. It works but if change sequence of `<td>` and append in the code, the order doesn't change and remains as it is. Why?

```
 <table id="tbl" style="width: 80%; margin: auto" class="table table-bordered  table-hover mt-2">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr class="GridHeading">
                                                    <td>Remarks no</td>
                                                    <td>date</td>
                                                    <td>Statuses</td>
                                                    <td>Remarks by Date</td>                                            
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr></tr>


                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
```

code:

```
 var tr;
                if (data.ListRemarksHistory != null) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.ListRemarksHistory.length; i++) {
                        tr = $('<tr/>');
                        tr.append("<td>" + data.ListRemarksHistory[i].Remarks + "</td>");

                        tr.append("<td>" + data.ListRemarksHistory[i].User + "</td>");

                        tr.append("<td>" + data.ListRemarksHistory[i].Status + "</td>");

                        tr.append("<td>" + formatDate(data.RemarksHis[i].RemarksDate) + "</td>");

                        $('#tbl').append(tr);
                    }
}
```

Update:

see I change the tds in html table and to match that I change the order of tds that are getting appending... it doesn't change. Order stays the same

Comment: Not clear what you're asking.  "Change sequence of" - of what?  [edit: found the hidden td]  "order doesn't change" - order of what?

Comment: see I change the tds in html table and to match that I change the order of tds that are getting appending... it doesn't change. Order stays the same

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: I'm not "seeing" any "change".  Can you provide before/after code?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```
if (data.ListRemarksHistory.length) {
  $.each(data.ListRemarksHistory, function(i, item) {
    var tr = $("<tr>", {
      id: "row-" + i
      class: "remark-row"
    }).appendTo($("#tbl"));
    $("<td>").html(item.Remarks).appendTo(tr);
    $("<td>").html(item.Users).appendTo(tr);
    $("<td>").html(item.Status).appendTo(tr);
    $("<td>").html(item.RemarkDate).appendTo(tr);
  });
}
```

`$.each()` is made to iterate over Arrays or Objects. It can be very useful for data of this nature. Based on your post, `data.ListRemarksHistory` appears to be an Object.